# Perl script seg faults in Cmenu

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault

I am getting a core dump when I use the [Cmenu](http://p3rl.org/Cmenu) module on Solaris 8. The script works fine on Solaris 10.  Could somebody please suggest a possible workaround for this? Using dbx shows the following:

```
terminated by signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address)

Current function is Perl_safesysmalloc
92   Ptr = (Malloc_t)PerlMem_malloc(size?size:1)

 Perl_safesysmalloc(size = 4U), line 92 in "util.c"
```

I built version 5.10 of Perl using gcc on this machine. Please let me know if you have need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a bug on the module. Send a bug report to the author!

... though, the last release is from 2001, probably not being maintained anymore :-(

Answer (score 2):

Cmenu is a pure perl module that uses Curses.pm which is based on a C library. So mosts probable place for core dump is Curses.pm. Try upgrading it to latest version. Also try upgrading curses library.

If this does not help, try minimizing your program to get a minimal program that would still result a core dump. Report it to [Cmenu bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Cmenu).